# Data transformations for severely positively skewed data

Tags: data-transformation, normalization, z-score

I have 2 variables in my dataset that are severely positively skewed. I have tried the most common transformations to no avail, including log, inverse, and Box-Cox. Is there any other type of transformation that might normalise these data? Could a z-score be used?
I am using SPSS, so any syntax that can be provided would also be appreciated where possible.

Comment: I doubt that z-score would be useful since it doesn’t change the shape. It’d be useful if you could include a plot of your data as well.

Comment: Trying lots of transformations will distort statistical inference badly.  Since you don't know the transformation up front, use a semiparametric regression model such as the proportional odds model that makes no assumption about the transformation.